# Formula alone copy paste without change

Tags: vba, excel, excel-formula, formulas

I asked the same question earlier. But I am unable to get the exact result. Kindly help me to get it through VBA macro. Thanks.

Question:
How to copy formula alone for a particular range (say A10:A20) and paste it in next column. I can do the same for single cell in Excel by press F2 and copy that formula alone and paste it in the next column. But if I want to select a range and paste in next column what I have to do?

Please remember: Answer won't change as I am selecting same formula.

Comment: Use PasteSpecial

Comment: Is it an option for you to use [absolute address](https://www.gcflearnfree.org/excel2016/relative-and-absolute-cell-references/1/) with `$`? Let's say if your formula is `=A1 + 1` and you copy it to another column it will change eg. to `=B1 + 1`. But if you use absolute addresses like `=$A$1 + 1` and copy it then it will stay `=$A$1 + 1`. So usually this is the way you go.

Comment: Yes boss. you are right. I didn't think about that option. Thanks. Please help me on my other query. I hope that one is little tricky. But is requires for my income reversal working.

Answer (score 1):

To copy a formula from one range/column to another you can do it like this:

```
Option Explicit

Sub CopyFormulasFromBtoC()
    With Worksheets("Sheet1")
        .Range("C:C").Formula = .Range("B:B").Formula
    End With
End Sub
```

This is also possible for ranges instead of columns, but the ranges need to be exactly the same size.

```
.Range("C1:C7").Formula = .Range("B1:B7").Formula
```

> **Note:**
>   If it is an option for you to use [absolute addresses](https://www.gcflearnfree.org/excel2016/relative-and-absolute-cell-references/1/) in your formula then this would be the preferred way to go instead of a macro like above.

Comment: @Rajesh Please consider marking this answer as solution then, so everybody can see that it is solved.

Answer (score 0):

[examle of the excel page - c2 is the formula to c1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TKO95.png)

first in the formula be sure to use "$" to make the range address absolute

the button code is

```
Sub Button1_Click()
Sheets("Sheet1").Columns(3).Copy Destination:=Sheets("Sheet1").Columns(4)
End Sub
```

you can also use

```
Range("D:D").Value = Range("C:C").Value
```